# Install app on Nexus Player [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android

After updated my android sdk tools to 24.0.2, platform-tools to 21, build-tools to 21.1.2, Android platform to 5.0.1 (API 21), I can't install or debug my TV app on the nexus player anymore.

for example, if I do,
$ adb install ~/Downloads/AndroidTV-release.apk 
3309 KB/s (4576141 bytes in 1.350s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/AndroidTV-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Is there any one see the same and knows the fix? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your manifest or your build.gradle, you have set minSdkVersion higher than version installed in your Nexus Player.